# trying to set a set of strings into a 2d array as chars, in java

Tags: java, char

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

/**
 * Auto-generated code below aims at helping you parse
 * the standard input according to the problem statement.
 **/
class Solution {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int w = in.nextInt(); // width of the strings
        int h = in.nextInt(); // number of strings
        char[][] answer = new char[w][h];
        if (in.hasNextLine()) {
            in.nextLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            for(int j = 0; j < w; j++){
                answer[i][j] = line.charAt(j);
                System.out.print(answer[i][j]);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

//throws out an exception (.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 9 out of bounds for length 9) //bascially what im trying to do its say for example the input is this:

3

3

...

...

...

//the width would be 3, height 3, and im trying to fill out the array with chars of the strings
//im a bit new to java but i like solving puzzles like this and this one is eating me alive

Comment: Your answer array should be height, width.

Comment: char[][] answer = new char[h][w]; you can create char array with height , width

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure on what you're asking, but I am guessing you're looking for something like this:

```java
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            String line;
            while (true) {
                line = in.nextLine();
                if (line.length() == w)
                    break;
                else
                    System.out.println("Please enter a string of length "+w);
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < w; j++){
                answer[i][j] = line.charAt(j);
                System.out.print(answer[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: yes this worked, thank you a bunch, i was really stuck, this managed to avoid the exception which was a big problem <3

Comment: @OwlGifter nps, if u don't mind accepting this as the answer then, so I can get the sweet stackoverflow points :)